# Why does large Jupyter notebook start consuming 100% CPU after every command invocation?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a big Jupyter notebook (consuming 150+ **Gigabytes** of RAM). When I run a command, including something as simple as 1+1, I get the answer, but right after that, the notebook starts taking up 100% of CPU. The memory usage starts increasing steadily, reaching over 230 GB, before dropping back down to 150 GB ish. If I interrupt the kernel right after I get the answer, I can run another command. However, right after giving the answer to that command, the process again starts consuming 100% CPU. It seems like some kind of garbage collector that runs after every invocation? Is this happening due to the large memory footprint of my notebook? Is there any way I can avoid this behavior?

Version info:
jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.2
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 7.9.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.3
jupyter client   : 5.3.4
jupyter lab      : 1.1.4
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.3
python           : 3.6.9

Comment: does you see the behavior if you run `print(1 + 1)` instead of just `1 + 1`?

Comment: Yes, I see the same behavior even with print(1+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out (by trial and error) that the reason for the slowdown was a Notebook extension called "Variable Inspector". Disabling it makes this problem go away and my notebooks are fast and responsive once again :)